# Colorbar tick values and labels do not match

Tags: python, matplotlib

**My code**:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

contour_levels = [10,100,500,1000,10000]
h = np.histogram2d(np.random.normal(0,2,10000),np.random.normal(0,2,10000),bins=10)
c = ax.contourf(h[0].T,cmap='magma',norm=LogNorm(),levels=contour_levels,extend='both')
cbar = plt.colorbar(c)
ticks = cbar.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()

cbar.ax.tick_params(which='minor',size=8,width=1,colors='white')
cbar.ax.tick_params(which='major',size=15,width=1,colors='white')
[t.set_color('black') for t in ticks]

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

**The result**:

[image]

```py
>print(ticks)

[Text(1, 10.0, '$\\mathdefault{10^{1}}$'),
 Text(1, 56.234132519034915, '$\\mathdefault{10^{2}}$'),
 Text(1, 316.2277660168379, ''),
 Text(1, 1778.2794100389228, '$\\mathdefault{10^{3}}$'),
 Text(1, 10000.0, '$\\mathdefault{10^{4}}$')]
```

**Issue**:

Quite alarmingly, the colorbar tick labels only match the corresponding tick value on the first and last ticks! The bizarre locations of the minor ticks hinted at the major tick labels being wrongly placed (except for the minor ticks leading to 10^4).

Any idea of what is going on? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the colorbar ticks for a contour plot are distributed uniformly (same distance for each color). You can change this to `spacing='proportional'` to have each color use its corresponding proportion of the colorbar.

(With `color='white'` instead of `colors=...` in the `tick_params`, only the colors of the ticks themselves are changed, not the tick labels.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

contour_levels = [10, 100, 500, 1000, 10000]
h, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(np.random.normal(0, 2, 10000), np.random.normal(0, 2, 10000), bins=10)
h[h == 0] = np.nan
cont = ax.contourf((xedges[:-1] + xedges[1:]) / 2, (yedges[:-1] + yedges[1:]) / 2, h.T, cmap='magma', norm=LogNorm(),
                   levels=contour_levels, extend='both')

cbar = plt.colorbar(cont, ticks=contour_levels, format='%.0f', spacing='proportional')
ticks = cbar.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()
cbar.ax.tick_params(which='minor', size=8, width=1, color='white', direction='in')
cbar.ax.tick_params(which='major', size=15, width=1, color='white', direction='in')

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: colorbar for contourf with proportional ticks]

Comment: Wow I see, thank you very much! Is that mentioned in the docs? Isn't it a bug that should be fixed though? I don't think there is a dubious line in my code which would deservedly cause the tick values and labels to not match correctly..

Comment: The default colorbar has `spacing='uniform'`.  Whichever is preferred depends on many factors.

Comment: Thank you for the detail about the ```color``` instead of ```colors```. And sorry for missing the ```direction='in'``` ;)